# Launch Image on iPad only in PortraitMode (Only device)

Tags: ios, ipad, device, uilaunchimagefile

I wrote an iPad app and I'm using two different images as launch images. 
The iOS simulator shows the proper image during startup but the device always uses the portrait image. I have the right file size (Xcode does NOT give me any warnings)!

I'm using iOS5 Beta 7 with Xcode 4.2

Here is what I did so far:

- I double checked all the file sizes
- I readded the files to the project,
- I build the project from scratch (including 'Clean')
- I cleaned the workspace's derived data directory.
- I deleted the app completely from the device.
- I restarted the device.

I'm running out of ideas.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I couldnt find any mistakes. So I removed everything according the launchimage from the project (including entries in info.plist), deleted the derived workspace folder, deleted the app from the device. Inserted the pictures again an set the basename for the image in info.plist. It worked. still don't know why.

Btw: It seems like Xcode 4.2 (and iOS5) changes the sizes of the launch images for the iPad.

iOS < 5: Portrait 768x1004px Landscape: 1024x748px ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12))

iOS = 5: Portrait 768x1024px Landscape: 1024x768px (Source: Image)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for convincing me to stop trying to fix it and just delete all the .png's, delete the .plist entries, clean the build, shut down Xcode, delete the app from my device, and just go back into it fresh and drop the images in. Finally ready to submit!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 3.2 and later, an iPad application can provide both landscape and portrait versions of its launch images. Each orientation-specific launch image must include a special modifier string in its filename. The format for orientation-specific launch image filenames is as follows:

```
basename_usage_specific_modifiers_scale_modifier_device_modifier.png
```

[Application Launch Images.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already knew that. Still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

1. Rename image to Default-Landscape~ipad.png
2. In Info.plist register it as

> Blockquote

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile~ipad</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}/Default.png</string>
```

> Blockquote

and it seems to work...